# I Need to add methods to a Stack like Add(), Subtract(), Mult(), etc

Tags: java

Need to add methods to a Stack like Add(), Subtract(), Mult(), etc

I need to implement methods from an extended class and interface I am not understanding how exactly to implement these methods. As in how to I tell the stack to pop out two numbers, add them, and give me the result? Not wanting the answer just wanting some help as to how to get the right answer.

Sorry if this question if off topic or has been asked already I did do a bit of searching but did not find anything.

Thank you all for your time,
Simon

```
package calculatorRPN;

public class ForthStack extends ArrayStack implements Forth{

       @Override
    public double add() {

    }

    @Override
    public double sub() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public double mult() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public double div() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public double dup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public double twoDup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, if you call `add()`, then you want to pop the top two items, add them together, and return the result?

Your class extends `ArrayStack`, which means it already has the `pop()` method.

So you can do it like so:

```
public double add() {
    if (this.size() >= 2) {
        // pop the top item, then pop the new top item as well, and add them together
        return (this.pop() + this.pop());
    } else {
        // not enough items to perform add function
        return -1; // instead you should probably throw an error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're interested in learning how to pop items from an ArrayStack, which your class extends.

If that's the case, the [documentation for ArrayStack](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.html), might point you in the right direction without giving you the answer.